# How to Call Multiple Functions Of Angularjs On Page Load

Tags: html, angularjs, function

I'm Call Multiple Functions To Load Data In One Page. I Use This To Call One Function on Page Load.

```
data-ng-init="fn_load()"
```

But I Want To Call More Functions Of Angularjs On Page Load.. How It Can Be Done?

Comment: like this `data-ng-init="getAllProjects1();init();setMsgNotification();getUserById();setFlag()"`

Comment: You might have more chances of getting an answer if you stop capitalising every word.

Answer (score 1):

In your ng-init write a function called **callAllFunctions**

And write this in your controller

```
$scope.callAllFunctions = function(){

 getAllProjects1();
 init();
 setMsgNotification();‌​
 getUserById();
 setFla‌​g();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use initialisation stuff in Controller like,

```
var init = function()
{
 // declaring variables..

 // functions to load
 function1();
 $scope.function2();
}

init();
```